# BBM Connected app In BB 10 cascades

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, bb-messenger

I am developing one Trading Application in BB 10 Cascades.now I would like to add/show  this application to BBM.

I have downloaded BBM registration App from https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/bbmregistration and Integrated to my Tadrading Application successfully.

My Question is , Is my app is showm in BBM Connected list if my Trading App registered successfully with BBM?

Do I need to use BBM Social Platform API for That?

I am new to BBM Development and It's Platform Featuers. Looking forward for helping hand to get out of this.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have used the registration sample and successfully registered with the BBM Social Platform, your application should be listed in BBM within the apps section of your user profile.  Instead of trying to explain where to see that, have a look at a video I created on the BBM SP here:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efDHIbRbeho&feature=youtu.be

That video also demonstrates other BBM SP features like status updates and profile boxes.

Comment: Hello MShom,I have connected to BBM by integrating BBM registration App. now In BBM App list, App is displaying with default App icon.How can I change default app icon to my own app Icon.Please Help!!!